# Kotlin infix functions as first class objects not supported?

Tags: function, kotlin, infix-notation

I realized that when you declare a function object reference as val or var, you can't declare it as infix.

If you declare a function with fun, you can declare it as infix, but you can't assign another funcion reference to it.
This seems like a huge omission to me if I'm correct. Yes, I could somehow? nest the declaration in a higer order function, but it's not what I want.

To summarise:

```
infix fun Int.foo(x:Int)  { println(this+x) }
infix fun Int.boo(x:Int)  { println(this+x+1) }

fun main() {
    var coo: Int.(Int) -> Unit = Int::foo // allowed & works
    1 foo 1 // 2
    1.coo(1) // 2
    coo = Int::boo
    1.coo(1) // 3
    // No way to assign to Int::foo - error
    Int::foo = Int:boo 
    1 foo 1 // 3?
```

So I was looking for something like:

```
    infix var coo: Int.(Int) -> Unit = Int::foo
```

or

```
    var coo: infix Int.(Int) -> Unit = Int::foo
```

Apparently var/val function declarations can't be infix and infix is not part of the reference structure/type. Is this just not supported or am I missing something here?

Any other possible solutions for this? Thanks!

Comment: If that would be possible, then how would you differentiate a infix function from a infix variable? And that would be very confusing as well, because how would you refer a real function not the variable in the scope (if they had same name)?

Comment: If it's a function object stored in a local variable, it's likely not going to be used often. Infix functions are pretty much just syntactic sugar, and you can make do without them

Comment: This `Int::foo = Int::boo` doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to replace an object's methods, and how would that even work? That could lead to all sorts of vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: design aside, the concept of re-defiing an aoperator for a DSL is quite common. So setting up seperate functionality for an infix operator is quite common.

Comment: @Animesh Sahu I guess this would be infered from the context. But at least we should be able to assign functions later, in fun delcared identifiers?